# Is this Proof clear? Proof that $a^{1/n}$ converges to $1$ wherer $n$ is a natural number and $a>0$ is a real number

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing

> Proof that $a^{1/n}$ converges to $1$ wherer $n$ is a natural number and $a>0$ is a real number

Is this proof well written? Probably not. If not can anyone help me how to improve it?

**Step 0** Let $n$ denote a natural number. We are going to use the lemma that $a \leq b$ $\iff $ $a^n \leq b^n$ where $a,b$ are two real numbers $>0$. We are also going to use the squeeze theorem and the binomial theorem. We will first construct a lower bound then an upper bound for $a \geq 1$ and then we are going to generalize it for $0<a<1$.

**Step 1** Let $a \geq 1$. We will show that $1 \leq a^{1/n}$. This is equivalent to $1 \leq a$. But this is true by assumption and thus we have a lower bound.

**Step 2** Lets consider $a^{1/n} \leq 1 +\frac{a}{n}$. This is equivalent to $a \leq (1+\frac{a}{n})^{n}$. We can use the binomial theorem here and we find that it is equal to $1+n \frac{a}{n}1^{n}+...=1+a+...$. Then we combine this and we have that $a \leq 1+a+...$ but this is obviously true.

**Step 3** We now have achieved the following for a real number $a \geq 1$ we have that $1 \leq a^{1/n} \leq 1+a/n$. And by the squeeze theorem this converges to 1.

**Step 4** Last and least we need to show the same thing for $0 <a <1$. We can rewrite this into $a^{1/n}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{a})^{1/n}}$. But because if $a <1$ then $1/a > 1$ but because this is also a real number we can use the theorem we just proved and apply the quotient rule for limits.

Thus we are done.

Comment: You should write the Step 4 more carefully at the end. Other than that the proof is correct.

Comment: ok ty for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative to Step 2:**

For any $\epsilon>0$, you will find $n$ such that $$a^{1/n}<1+\epsilon.$$

Indeed, by Bernouilli's inequality (weaker than the generalized binomial theorem).

$$a^{1/n}\le1+\epsilon\iff a\le(1+\epsilon)^n\impliedby a\le1+n\epsilon$$ and one can use

$$n=\frac{a-1}{\epsilon}.$$

Comment: Thank you for this contribution. I also wanted to use an epsilon-Proof but I think I am blind xD. This is simpler and better.